# Transpose a dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

how can I do to transpose the following data frame in Pyspark?

The idea is to achieve the result that appears below.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id' : pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']),
     'place' : pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']),
     'value' : pd.Series([10, 30, 20, 10, 30, 20, 10, 30, 20], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']),
     'attribute' : pd.Series(['size', 'height', 'weigth', 'size', 'height', 'weigth','size', 'height', 'weigth'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'])}

   id place  value attribute
a   1     A     10      size
b   1     A     30    height
c   1     A     20    weigth
d   2     A     10      size
e   2     A     30    height
f   2     A     20    weigth
g   3     A     10      size
h   3     A     30    height
i   3     A     20    weigth

d = {'id' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'place' : pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A'], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'size' : pd.Series([10, 30, 20], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'height' : pd.Series([10, 30, 20], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'weigth' : pd.Series([10, 30, 20], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

   id place  size  height  weigth
a   1     A    10      10      10
b   2     A    30      30      30
c   3     A    20      20      20
```

Any help is welcome. From already thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-dataframe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all I don't think your sample output is correct. Your input data has size set to 10, height set to 30 and weigth set to 20 for every id, but the desired output set's everything to 10 for id 1. If this is really what you, please explain it a bit more. If this was a mistake, then you want to use the [pivot](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) function. Example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
l =[( 1        ,'A', 10, 'size' ),
( 1        , 'A', 30, 'height' ),
( 1        , 'A', 20, 'weigth' ),
( 2        , 'A', 10, 'size' ),
( 2        , 'A', 30, 'height' ),
( 2        , 'A', 20, 'weigth' ),
( 3        , 'A', 10, 'size' ),
( 3        , 'A', 30, 'height' ),
( 3        , 'A', 20, 'weigth' )]

df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['id','place', 'value', 'attribute'])

df.groupBy(df.id, df.place).pivot('attribute').agg(first("value")).show()

+---+-----+------+----+------+ 
| id|place|height|size|weigth|
+---+-----+------+----+------+ 
|  2|    A|    30|  10|    20| 
|  3|    A|    30|  10|    20| 
|  1|    A|    30|  10|    20|
+---+-----+------+----+------+
```

Comment: Thank you! that is what I was looking for!

Comment: is there a way to replace the null values with 0? My output has null values

Comment: Sure [fillna](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna).

Comment: In my case where I was transposing a df with 100s of columns, I needed to increase the max allowed pivot vals with this command:

spark.conf.set('spark.sql.pivotMaxValues', u'1000')

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot). `Pivoting` is always done in context to aggregation, and I have chosen `sum` here. So, if for same *id*, *place* or *attribute*, there are multiple values, then their sum will be taken. You could use min,max or mean as well, depending upon what you need.

```
df = df.groupBy(["id","place"]).pivot("attribute").sum("value")
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171023/pyspark-how-to-transpose-a-dataframe) also addresses the same question.