# Pivot in pySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe:

```
student_id class score
1 A 6
1 B 7
1 C 8
```

I would like to divide the `class` score into 3 columns so the above dataframe should become:

```
student_id class_A_score class_B_score class_C_score
1 6 7 8
```

The idea is to convert `A B C` into 3 columns.

Comment: @eliasah Can you help me see the similarity between OP's question and the link you provided.

Comment: Duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171023/pyspark-how-to-transpose-a-dataframe

Comment: @eliasah I am skeptical about the method you mentioned, please see if the answers to this question are what you were pointing to.

Comment: I've miss read the question @RahulChawla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
values = [(1,'A',6),(1,'B',7),(1,'C',8)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['student_id','class','score'])
df.show()
+----------+-----+-----+
|student_id|class|score|
+----------+-----+-----+
|         1|    A|    6|
|         1|    B|    7|
|         1|    C|    8|
+----------+-----+-----+
df = df.groupBy(["student_id"]).pivot("class").sum("score")
df.show()
+----------+---+---+---+
|student_id|  A|  B|  C|
+----------+---+---+---+
|         1|  6|  7|  8|
+----------+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of pivot. In pyspark, if `df` is your dataframe:

```
new_df = df.groupBy(['student_id']).pivot('class').sum(score)
```

Databricks has very nice illustration of this at https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html